# How to find Arch lib in py?

Tags: python, time-series

Where I can find the arch library to do the PP- filter for time series analysis for non-stationary time series?
I can't find it in packages in Anconda Navigator

Comment: Can't find it in anaconda navigator

Comment: Can't find what? Please tell us what you're looking for exactly – better still if you have e.g. a documentation link.

Comment: Have you tried [`conda install arch-py -c conda-forge`](https://github.com/bashtage/arch#anaconda)? Note `arch-py` and not `arch`.

Comment: @Timeless thanks a lot mate, you just saved the day